# How to change the color of dividers between Actionbar tabs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Came around lot of solutions but none of them couldn't help my problem ...Actually i was trying to change the color of dividers in actionbar tabs....

```
<style name="CustomTabBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider_hori</item>
        <item name="divider">@drawable/divider_hori</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="android:measureWithLargestChild">true</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">5dip</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">5dip</item>
    </style>
```

if i use this code in my custom theme as everyone say...In reaction helps me to remove only the default divider ...but it's not drawing the divider which i had specified in "@drawable/divider_hori "
don't know wheather i have to use a 9 patch image or an xml...by the way my drawable/divider_hori looks like

xml - divider_hori

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line" >
            <gradient android:angle="90" >
                <stroke
                    android:width="3dp"
                    android:color="#9f9f9f" />

                <gradient>
                </gradient>
            </gradient>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

so need help in this .....

Comment: Is that the entire xml of your drawable?

Comment: <item name="android:dividerPadding">5dip</item>

<item name="android:dividerHeight">5dip</item>

Remove this statements then check it

Comment: The drawable XML is incomplete--I don't see the opening `<layer-list>` tag--but just from what you posted your XML is bad. The `<stroke>` element should be inside of `<shape>`, not inside of `<gradient>`, and you also have an extra empty `<gradient>` that doesn't need to be there at all. Why do you need a `<layer-list>` for dividers?

Comment: @Karakuri Thanks for edit ...And Opening tag missed while Copying .... I know my Xml is completely wrong...so what about this  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#9e9e9e"
        android:endColor="#9e9e9e"
        android:startColor="#9e9e9e" />

</shape>

Comment: @Karakuri ...if u have any xml regarding Dividers,can u link it here....it would be a great help..

Comment: @palak....i did what u said but no use ....sorry

Comment: Just as a test, try changing the dividers to just a color: `android:divider="#ffff0000"`. This should turn the dividers red.